# Rendering button inside ng-content failed

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ng-content in angular5. My tag has a simple html5 button, which I want to render. But is not showing as button after rendering.

Please have a look at this slack. [slack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsnxpu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You do not use `<ng-content>` like this. If you want to transclude content, you put it between the element tags, like this (I'm going to keep your element names):

```
<app-comp1>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</app-comp1>
```

If you really need to render an html string, you need to inject `DomSanitizer` and use the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` method. Like this:

app.component.html

```
<app-comp1>
  <div [innerHTML]="safeStr"></div>
</app-comp1>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  str1 = `
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  `
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  get safeStr() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.str1);
  }

}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48ge4y)

Comment: But I am getting that string from a service. Cant set it at design time. I am able to generate button button using SafeHtml but the click event is not working. Another slack is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuo4wj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: That I have already done, but how to use click event in that button. Can you please try.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that there is a way to keep the angular bindings on a string.